# Linespacing varies from line to line

Tags: line-spacing

Working on my thesis, I have found out strange variation in line spacing.

I am using `\documentclass{book}`, and the function `\sloppy`.

[image]

As you can see, between lines 3-4 and 4-5 line spacing has changed a lot... How can I have a constant line spacing? Thanks!

---

EDIT : Unfortunately, my example was poorly chosen. In order to show the variable line spacing, I reduced my font size.
But in reality, I want a font size of 12 and a line spacing of 12.8.
I tried your two solutions, unfortunately the spacing is still varying...

[image]

Here's my code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm, heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage[cam,width=17.5truecm,height=25.54truecm,center,dvips,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[newparttoc]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{BCBDC0}
\definecolor{white}{HTML}{FFFFFF}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\usepackage{emptypage}


\usepackage{leading}
%\leading{12.8pt}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settodepth{\dimen0}{\textit{fj}gjpqy}% characters with big depth
  \settoheight{\dimen2}{É}% characters with big height
  \leading{\dimexpr\dimen0+\dimen2+0.8pt}%
}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}


\newcounter{subpara}
\setcounter{subpara}{0}
\newcommand\numsubpara[1]{\vspace{0.5cm}\par\refstepcounter{subpara} \fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \thesubpara. \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont \space#1\space\vspace{0.3cm}\\  \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}

%*****
% Footnotes
%*****

\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3pt}}


\let\oldfootnote\footnote
    \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\leading{10.2pt} \fontsize{8.5}{12}\selectfont   #1}}
    \long\def\@makefnmark{%
        \hbox {\@textsuperscript {\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont  \@thefnmark}}
        }

\begin{document}


\numsubpara{Finalit\'es du droit de la concurrence.\protect\footnote{V. BONASSIES, Les fondements du droit communautaire de la concurrence : la th\'eorie de la concurrence-moyen, in M\'elanges Weill, 1983, 51 ; LE TOURNEAU, Libert\'e, \'egalit\'e, fraternit\'e dans le droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence}, Gaz. Pal., 1991, 2, Doctr., 348 ; GLAIS, \'Economie industrielle, 1992 ; Politique de concurrence, Rev. \'eco. ind., 1993, nº 63 ; DANET, Le droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} doit-il \^etre \'economiquement correct ?, D. Aff. 1996, 1370 ; VOGEL, droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} et puissance d'achat : plaidoyer pour un changement, JCP E, 1997, I, 713 ; GLAIS, Crises sectorielles et ententes d\'efensives, M\'elanges Champaud, 1997, 335 ; BIENAYM\'E, Principes de concurrence, 1998 ; FAG\`ES et MESTRE, L'emprise du droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} sur le contrat, RTD com., 1998, 71 ; droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} et droit priv\'e, Cah. dr. entr., 2000, nº 3 ; GUEDJ, Pratique du droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} national et communautaire, Litec, 2000 ; DEVELLENNES et KIRIAKIS, Vers un r\'eseau international de la concurrence, LPA, 18 d\'ecembre 2001 ; LUCAS de LEYSSAC et PARL\'EANI, Droit du march\'e, PUF, 2002 ; TORRE-SCHAUB, Essai sur la construction juridique de la cat\'egorie de march\'e, LGDJ, th\`ese, 2002 ; BOY, L'ordre concurrentiel : essai de d\'efinition d'un concept, M\'elanges Pirovano, 2003, 23 ; NEVEN, L'efficacit\'e des politiques de la concurrence : le point de vue d'un \'economiste (La perception et la mesure de l'efficacit\'e de la politique de la concurrence, 1re table ronde du colloque sur "L'efficacit\'e de la politique de la concurrence"), Gaz. Pal., 26-28 janvier 2003, 29 ; VOGEL, Le juriste face \`a l'analyse \'economique, Rev. conc. consom., 2003, 7 ; L'\'economie, serviteur ou ma\^itre du droit ?, M\'elanges Decocq, 2004, 605 ; BRAULT, Politique et pratique du droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} en France, LGDJ, 2005 ; COMBE, Economie et politique de la concurrence, Dalloz, 2005 ; DYEVRE, La prise en consid\'eration de crit\`eres "extraconcurrentiels" dans le droit communautaire de la concurrence, RID \'eco., 2007 nº 4, 415 ; VOGEL, Concurrence : de l'\'evolution \`a la r\'evolution, in Le Code de commerce\Index{Commerce}, Dalloz, 2007, 413 ; RIEM, Concurrence effective ou concurrence efficace ? L'ordre concurrentiel en trompe-l'{\oe}il, RID \'eco., 2008, nº 1, 67 ; ANDRIYCHUK, Dialectical antitrust: An alternative insight into the methodology of the EC competition law analysis in a period of economic downturn, ECLR, 2010, Vol. 31, Issue 4, 155 ; VOGEL, droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} et crise \'economique : qui est le plus fort ?, Liber Amicorum Christian Larroumet, Economica, 2010, 465 ; ABBOTT et SINGHAM, Enhancing welfare by attacking anticompetitive market distortions, Concurrences, 4/2011, n\degree 39547 ; ARCELIN-LECUYER, Proc\'edure de sauvegarde et concurrence : le divorce consomm\'e, D., 2011, 21, 1441 ; DECOCQ, Le droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} \`a l'\'epreuve de la crise \'economique et financi\`ere, Contrats Conc. Consom., 2012, rep\`ere n\degree 2 ; HUDSON, Understanding the Direction of EU Competition Law: An Analysis based on Merger Regulation in the EU and US, ECLR, 2012, Vol. 33, Issue 11, 526 ; GOLDMAN et VOGEL, Encyclopaedia Universalis, V. Concurrence, 2013 ; MEROLA, DERENNE, RIVAS, Competition law in times of economic crisis: In Need of Adjustment?, Bruylant, 2013 ; MAZIARZ, Do now economic goals count in interpreting Article 101(3) TFUE?, ECJ August 2014, 341.}}Au sens large, le droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} assure \`a la fois la libert\'e et la loyaut\'e de la concurrence. La plus grande partie de ses r\`egles prot\`ege le march\'e et s'oppose aux ententes, abus de position dominante ou concentrations qui suppriment ou r\'eduisent la concurrence entre les entreprises. Ce sont notamment les articles 101 et 102 TFUE ou le droit des pratiques anticoncurrentielles (art. L. 420-1 s. C. com.) en France. D'autres r\`egles emp\^echent les agissements fautifs des entreprises qui adoptent des comportements pr\'ejudiciables \`a l'\'egard de leurs concurrents ou de leurs Partenaire\Index{Partenaire!b}s, sans porter atteinte au fonctionnement du march\'e lui-m\^eme. Elles prot\`egent les concurrents, non la concurrence. De tels agissements sont susceptibles de constituer des actes de concurrence d\'eloyale ou encore, selon la classification fran\c{c}aise, des pratiques restrictives. Le droit europ\'een ne comporte pas, pour l'heure, de telles dispositions sanctionnant la concurrence d\'eloyale.

Au sens strict, le droit de la concurrence\Index{Droit de la concurrence} ne se pr\'eoccupe pas, en principe, de loyaut\'e de la concurrence. Inspir\'e du droit antitrust am\'ericain, il a pour objet unique de lutter contre le pouvoir de monopole ou de march\'e, c'est-\`a-dire la capacit\'e dont dispose une entreprise ou un groupe d'entreprises, qui contr\^ole une part relativement importante du march\'e, d'induire une hausse des prix en r\'eduisant les quantit\'es offertes et en obligeant ainsi les consommateurs \`a se d\'etourner vers d'autres biens, au risque de gaspiller des ressources \'economiques rares. Au-del\`a du bon fonctionnement du march\'e, c'est donc l'efficacit\'e \'economique et le bien-\^etre du consommateur qui sont en cause. Neutre au regard de la r\'epartition des ressources entre les diff\'erents op\'erateurs, le droit de la concurrence est d\'epourvu de toute pr\'eoccupation d'\'equit\'e. Il ne poursuit aucun objectif de justice distributive et ne vise qu'\`a accro\^itre le surplus global de l'\'economie. Il n'a pas non plus l'ambition de favoriser un agent \'economique particulier (par ex. le petit commer\c{c}ant par rapport au grand distributeur). Le pr\'esuppos\'e de l'id\'eologie concurrentielle classique est en effet que la situation de march\'e optimale r\'esulte de l'application pure et simple de la th\'eorie des prix et de sa cons\'equence juridique, la lutte contre le pouvoir de monopole. Il en r\'esulte que seules les r\`egles figurant aux articles 101 et 102 TFUE ou L. 420-1 et suivants du Code de commerce\Index{Commerce}, ou dans le r\`eglement sur le contr\^ole des concentrations, rel\`event \`a proprement parler du droit de la concurrence. Tel qu'il est con\c{c}u aujourd'hui, le contr\^ole des aides d'\'Etat, qui figure aussi au chapitre du Trait\'e consacr\'e aux r\`egles de concurrence, ne s'inscrit pas dans le cadre de la th\'eorie des prix mais repr\'esente plut\^ot un avatar de la concurrence d\'eloyale.

\`A la diff\'erence du droit am\'ericain, le droit europ\'een et le droit fran\c{c}ais n'ont jamais con\c{c}u les finalit\'es du droit de la concurrence, m\^eme entendu comme le droit des pratiques anticoncurrentielles et des concentrations, exclusivement en termes d'efficacit\'e \'economique. En recourant \`a la notion de concurrence praticable ou efficace, ils n'ont pas h\'esit\'e, lorsqu'ils l'ont jug\'e n\'ecessaire, \`a rejeter le dogme de la th\'eorie des prix et \`a faire des choix positifs en faveur de certains sch\'emas de consommation. Dans l'arr\^et Metro2, le juge europ\'een d\'eclare que "la concurrence non fauss\'ee vis\'ee aux articles 3 et 85 du Trait\'e CE [devenu 101 TFUE] implique l'existence sur le march\'e d'une concurrence efficace (workable competition), c'est-\`a-dire de la dose de concurrence n\'ecessaire pour que soient respect\'ees les exigences fondamentales et atteints les objectifs du Trait\'e...". En cons\'equence, les autorit\'es europ\'eennes et fran\c{c}aises pr\'ef\`erent parfois \`a la concurrence par les prix, la concurrence par la qualit\'e, et ne consid\`erent pas que la protection de l'environnement, de l'emploi ou du petit commerce\Index{Commerce}, ou la lutte contre les abus de puissance d'achat des grands distributeurs \`a l'\'egard de leurs fournisseurs sont des pr\'eoccupations extraconcurrentielles. L'opposition entre la politique europ\'eenne de concurrence et la th\'eorie \'economique n'est cependant pas si absolue car les fins ext\'erieures au raisonnement concurrentiel sont aussi des facteurs de co\^ut qu'une analyse \'economique plus globale devrait prendre en consid\'eration.


\end{document}
```

Comment: There's no obvious reason for the decrease in spacing between the lines.  It's very unusual to have lines spaced more closely.  (It's very common for lines to be spaced more widely when math with fractions, for example, is involved.)  It's possible that the presence of footnotes is increasing the spacing, as well as the accented "É".  In fact, it's not clear what the intended spacing *should* be.  Please provide a small compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.  That should provide the necessary information.

Comment: It works, thank you ! 2 questions : 
1) Is there a way to do it automatically? 2) Which characters are implying this strange space line? "É" and footnotes only ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I will edit my post with an example in a few minutes, thank you !

Comment: @barbarabeeton done !

Comment: @barbara beeton: the initial question contained the use of a 12pt font-size (this is a measurement of the M-height, not the full line-height), but the user specified a "leading" valee of 7pt, assuming that this was the traditional typographic measurement of the gap between the absolute top of the line and the top of the "M-height"). It was evidently too small to fit at least the font-size, and all rows were rendered with a much too narrow spacing (see how ascenders and descenders are almost touching in that case, or how they could collide with some glyphs with tall descenders or extra "decorat

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is a misunderstanding of the meaning of `\leading`.

In the package `leading`, the command `\leading` is defined so that it "sets the leading immediately to the  specified."

[**Edit:** It is necessary to point out here that the term "leading" as used in the `leading` package does *not* have the same meaning as it does in traditional metal typesetting.  This answer addresses the practice of using (La)TeX to typeset European languages, in particular French, as illustrated by the example in the question, using a particular package.]

"Leading" is defined by the `leading` package to be the same as `\baselineskip`.  You have specified `12pt` as the document size option.  This size, "set solid", would have a baseline-to-baseline distance of 12 points.  But you also specify `\leading{7pt)`.  This is less than the required baseline distance, but since TeX won't overprint lines unless special measures are applied, the lines are set as close as possible to one another; that is governed by the height of footnote markers or accents above, and the depth of descenders below.

What I *think* you want to to add 7pt of spacing (what is often called "leading" in metal typesetting) to what is ordinarily placed between lines.  So

```
\leading{19pt}
```

would accomplish that.

As an aside, use of `\sloppy` usually results in poor quality spacing throughout a document.  Better results can be obtained by using a language-specific application of a package like `polyglossia` or `babel` to enable proper hyphenation, and applying paragraph-specific `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` only where needed.

**Edit 2:**
The recommended distance between baselines is often 20% of the type size.  Thus, in many traditional journals, the type is set at 10-on-12 points.  For 12pt text, that recommendation would be 12-on-14.4, which is sometimes rounded down to 14pt.  The desired setting specified in the question is 12-on-12.8; this is too close to accommodate accented uppercase letters, as illustrated by the wider space above the line containing the "É".  (This rather tight spacing may be enough to accommodate footnotes, but this should be checked, as none appear in the added image.)

To handle the "É" as a manual exception (which is necessary to obtain evenly spaced lines with the desired baseline distance), this coding can be used:

```
d'\smash{\`E}tat
```

If a font with pre-accented letters is used, and the input is encoded as `utf8` with pre-accented letters, it might be possible to modify *in the font* the stated height of accented uppercase letters, but I'm not competent to provide a specific method.  This could have undesired side effects in other environments, which I'm unwilling to predict.

Comment: in summary, "\leading" does not provide the correct measurement of the real typographic leading,  it is actually a partial measurement of the line-height above the baseline (the sum of the leading and the M-height, ignoring the height of descenders and the trailing gap below that would be added to get the total line-heigth, i.e. the vertical distance between two lines)

Comment: Note that if your text is multilingual, a line may contain characters in scripts whose baseline is not at the same vertical position. In a multilingual text, the minimum line-height (for basic fonts) is 1.6em (consider scripts with tall characters like Burmese), or even higher (scripts with complex vertical clusters like Tibetan, or scripts whose baseline is not purely horizontal, but is reset to the initial position only at word boundaries, like Arabic in classic Persian/Urdu/Pashto style where words are typesetted and joined over a diagonal starting from the initial baseline)

Comment: @verdy_p -- The situation is confusing.  In the `leading` package, `\leading` is defined to specify the baseline-to-baseline distance.  (It may be defined differently in some other package, but the package used in the example in this question is `leading`.)  This is certainly different from the definition in traditional metal typography as applied to Western alphabetic languages, but one must be careful to determine the vocabulary used in the immediate environment.  Vocabulary, unfortunately, isn't uniform everywhere.

Comment: Beside this, any insertion of contents in specific styles may cause the need to increase the baseline for specific rows (e.g. the insertion of superscripts or subscripts, possibly on several levels, or the insertion of tall images).
So you have to setup a convenient line-height that will work, most of the time in a given language, but not necessarily everywhere: tallers rows may be needed anywhere at random place, unless you can place these contents outside the flow of the paragraph.

Comment: Hello @barbarabeeton, thank you for your answer, the use of leading is much clearer now. Unfortunately, even with ```\leading{12.8pt}```, I still have varying linespace. I have edited my post.

Comment: @Guliup -- In response to the addition to your post, I have added an explanation to this answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I might use this, it looks good ! How about footnotes? Is it possible to use the same code ?

Comment: Adapting this to be used with footnotes should be possible, but it's more complicated.  I can't work on an example right now, as I don't have access to a working TeX system.  (I hope that is just temporary!)

Answer (score 6):

The term *leading* comes from metal type technology, where letters were cut above rectangular pieces of metal all having the same height.

[image: https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-images-english-alphabet-metal-type-image25695894]

<sup>Image from https://www.dreamstime.com/</sup>

The typographer could change the space between lines of type by inserting strips of metal (made mostly of lead). The height of the types is the “font size”. If a page was set *solid*, no leading was used.

TeX uses a different approach, because its “types” don't have the same height. Instead of adding space between lines, it tries to achieve constant spacing between consecutive baselines (the imaginary lines where the characters sit upon) by setting the `\baselineskip` parameter.

In the standard LaTeX classes, the parameter `\baselineskip`, when the font size is 10 points is set to `12pt`.

With metal type it's impossible that characters in different lines overlap; this could be possible in TeX, if the baseline skip is too small. So TeX also adds another feature: if it computes that the maximum depth on a line plus the maximum height on the next line minus the baselineskip is less than the value of a parameter called `\lineskiplimit`, it inserts a vertical space of the amount of `\lineskip` instead of the vertical space that would guarantee even spacing between baselines.

It has become (unfortunately) common to call *leading* this distance between baselines. The `leading` package tries to solve the problem of avoiding computations by allowing to express the `\baselineskip` parameter instead of computing “standard `\baselineskip` times `\baselinestretch`”.

Indeed, LaTeX builds on TeX's model by using, along `\baselineskip` a parameter called `\baselinestretch`, that can be set with `\linespread{<number>}`. At begin document, the value of `\baselineskip` is multiplied by `\baselinestretch`. The `leading` package alleviates the problem allowing to state the result of the computation we want in order to achieve a certain baseline skip.

Why did TeX choose a different model? Because it is originally meant to produce mathematical texts. Typographer had a very hard time in typesetting mathematics, because they had to cut their block of type in order to accommodate subscripts and superscripts; big symbols made them cut the leading strips. All sorts of devious tricks were needed.

If you want to get something like the picture above, with, say, 7pt added between lines, you need to measure the maximum depth and height of characters, add a small amount (you see that the “g” doesn't reach the bottom, nor the “k” reaches the top) and add the amount of leading. This can certainly be done with the package.

Here I do the measurement described before, with 1pt of additional space and 7pt of (traditional) leading.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
  paperheight=240mm,
  paperwidth=160mm,
  left=22mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=20mm,
  bottom=22mm,
  heightrounded, % <--- don't forget
]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settodepth{\dimen0}{\textit{fj}gjpqy}% characters with big depth
  \settoheight{\dimen2}{É}% characters with big height
  \leading{\dimexpr\dimen0+\dimen2+1pt+7pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
plus restreint\footnote{A footnote}. Les marchés de la commercialisation
des voitures particulières\footnote{} ou de la réalisation d'ouvrages de
construction\footnote{} se limitent ainsi à l'État membre concerné. La
spécificité et l'homogénéité du produit das les differents pays de l'EEE
que seuls quelques fournisseurs sont capable de distribuer en grand
quantité et a bref délai pour…

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @egreg, thank you for your answer. I have tried using your piece of code in order to get a 12pt font and 12.8pt linespacing. Un fortunately, it keeps varying. I have edited my post with my code. Do you have any idea why it is not working ? Thank you in advance !

Comment: @Guliup 12.8pt is too small, particularly for French: a single É will ruin the spacing.

Comment: @Guliup With the code you added, the baseline skip is computed to 14.11989pt, which is not surprising.

Comment: @Guliup Here's what you'd get with 12.8 and a trick for making the lines equally spaced notwithstanding character overlapping [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuZD1.png) I find it disastrous.

Comment: I understand what you mean... You are right it does not look good. I am trying to reproduce a template created with indesign. This is where I get the values "12pt" and "12.8pt". 
With indesign, as you can see [here](https://ibb.co/sb7Tm7z), the result looks good. Does it mean that in fact, the line space is different than 12.8pt? Or the font is smaller than 12pt? I am quite confused, why would it look nice on indesign and not LaTeX ?

Comment: @Guliup I don't understand why there is such complicated disputation. Why do you simply set `\lineskiplimit` to a negative value and then only pray the letter g and É dont' meet at the same place one above others. I dont know what does Indesign but I mean that it keeps in such praying too.

Comment: Look at the picture you provided, particularly at the word “spécificité”. What would happen if instead of “EEE” below it it had “État”? The line spacing is definitely too tight and the typesetting looks quite inaccurate: the footnote numbers are misplaced, the apostrophes are not curly, Use 11pt and `\linespread{1.1}` or even `\linespread{1.2}`.